# Parse string to double

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a table from database where values in cells are string type:
1.4141,
2.012,
11.33,
And Im trying to parse them to double,but it throws FormatException (saying something like wrong entry format).There is a part of the code:

```
double a;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                a = Double.Parse(row[1].ToString());//here it throws the 
                    exception
            }
```

Comment: Most likely you're using comma as your decimal separator, can you verify this? Also, try `Double.Parse(row[1].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, what does `row[1].GetType()` give you?

Comment: Show us the content of `row[1]`

Comment: if it was a double, it would be roundtrip-safe: double.ToString() ==> double.Parse() so OP's claim that it is string makes sense. It must be the culture-specific decimal separator, or maybe a missing value or invalid value in some row(s)

Comment: The parsing of the string might not be needed at all depending on how the data is read from the database.

Comment: no,no,each value has it own cell in table cell,and row[1] is String type

Comment: It's also possible that your data contains an invalid value (if these are just strings in the DB). You won't really know what's wrong without looking at the value of `row[1].ToString()` that is failing.

Comment: all cells have values like this:1.088

Comment: then try what @Lasse suggests in the first comment, and if it still does not work edit the details into your question.

Comment: It works with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,thanks to all,problem solved